# Получение координат при загрузке KML-файла

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Загружаю файл KML. Пример содержимого:

`<Placemark><name>Точка</name><description><![CDATA[ 29-06-2018 13:18:12 ]]> </description><Point><coordinates>54.380501676378984,68.85314738754338</coordinates></Point></Placemark>`

При загрузке мне надо считать содержимое тэгов "description" и "coordinates".

```js
ymaps.geoXml.load('http://site.ru/1.kml')
            .then(function (res) {
                res.geoObjects.each(function (obj) {      
     desc=obj.properties.get('description');
     coord=obj.properties.get('coordinates');
});
```

Так вот, значение переменной "desc" получаю, а "coord" - undefined. Как мне координаты получить из файла?

Comment: Попробуйте: obj.geometry.getCoordinates();

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу сам себе:). Решил так:

```js
coord = res.geoObjects.get(i).geometry.getCoordinates();
```